# How to use personal access token with HTTPS urls from GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I want to use Peronal access token with git repo on GitHub. I've created the token. And created a test repo. I used the Access Token as my password as I use to do. But git gives an error that password authentication was removed in 2021.

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/jcubic/git-test.git
$ nano README.md
$ git add README.md
$ git commit -am 'init commit'
$ git push
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/jcubic/git-test.git/'
```

The documentation says:

> When Git prompts you for your password, enter your personal access token.

But it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong? Or what could be possible issues?

Comment: Note that *Git* does not give any errors here, it is Git*Hub* that gives an error here. Git just passes on whatever text you give it; it's GitHub that decides whether that text is a password, or a token, or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've contacted GitHub support and the error message was misleading. The actual error is: "that token needs write permission". I didn't check that option when creating a token, because the documentation that GitHub provides is also misleading. It says that "repo" permission is needed to access private repos, that may be right, but you also need "repo" permission if you want to push changes to the git repo.

So there are two bugs on the GitHub side here, one with a misleading error message and one with misleading documentation when creating an access token.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not enter your token, if there was no prompt, check your `git --global credential.helper` value.

If you have a [credential storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) set, check what credentials were registered for `github.com`:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git credential-xxx get
```

(replace `xxx` by your `credential.helper` value)

If you see your GitHub account password, instead of your token, that would explain the error message.

Change it with:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=jcubic\npassword=yourToken" | git credential-xxx store
```

If the token is there, double-check [its **scope**](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps)

> `repo`: Grants full access to public and private repositories including read and **write access** to code, commit statuses, repository invitations.

You can see the scope of a token with (as in [this thread](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/4295#issuecomment-917353429)) [gh repo list](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_list), to extract the `X-Oauth-Scopes` field

```
DEBUG=api gh repo list
```

Comment: I did enter my token and I did get the prompt. The documentation says that you don't need git credentials and that it's optional.

Comment: @jcubic Then try a recreate a [classic token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-personal-access-token-classic): test it on the next prompt for credentials.

Comment: I use classic token and I don't have `credential.helper` documentation says it's optional if you don't want to type credentials every time.

Comment: @jcubic `credential.helper` is the way to not type your credentials everytime.

Comment: I know what `credential.helper` is for, but I don't need it. I want to push once to test something. I use SSH when working with git. I need HTTPS to test the isomorphic-git library that uses HTTPS.

Comment: @jcubic Then using your token when prompted for a password should work.

Comment: But it doesn't. Ok, thanks for your help, I will ask GitHub support. And maybe add my own answer if I will find the solution.

Comment: There were two errors both on the GitHub side. You can read my answer if you're interested.

Comment: @jcubic I have completed my answer with the OAuth scope, and a way to check the scopes of an existing token.